# How to use smalivm and simplify to find a certain static constant from APK or remove confusion?

Tags: deobfuscation, apk

> smalivm: Provides a virtual machine sandbox for executing Dalvik methods. After executing a method, it returns a graph containing all possible register and class values for every execution path.

I want to find a static constant from a APK. Because of its use of obfuscation, the code is difficult to read. But I know that the constant is returned from a function after confusion, and I am sure that it is a fixed value. I think smalivm can find out the return value of this function, but I can't find a sample article that fully describes how smalivm is used except for [this article](http://calebfenton.github.io/2016/04/30/dalvik-virtual-execution-with-smalivm/). This got me into trouble.

I don't know much about simplify. Does simplify work equally well when not using smalivm?